# Can't sort by all array's items?

Tags: postgresql

Postgresq 9.6

json

```
 "availability": [
      {
        "qty": 25,
        "price": 1599,
        "is_available": true
      },
      {
        "qty": 72,
        "price": 3599,
        },
         "is_available": true
   ]
```

table with column **data**. Type is **jsonb**

If I want to sort first array's(**availability**) item by field "**price**" I this:

```
SELECT * 
from product prod
WHERE to_tsvector('english', prod.data) @@ to_tsquery('gram')
ORDER BY prod.data #> '{availability,0,price}' desc
```

OK.

But I need to sort all fields "**price**" in array **availability**

Smt like this (pseudo code)

```
SELECT * 
    from product prod
    WHERE to_tsvector('english', prod.data) @@ to_tsquery('gram')
    ORDER BY prod.data #> '{availability,*,price}' desc
```

I need to to order by "price" desc.

The result must be

First record of result is second json

```
"availability": [
      {
        "qty": 25,
        "price": 11599,
        "is_available": true
      },
      {
        "qty": 72,
        "price": 13599,
        },
         "is_available": true
     ]
...
"availability": [
      {
        "qty": 25,
        "price": 1599,
        "is_available": true
      },
      {
        "qty": 72,
        "price": 3599,
        },
         "is_available": true
     ]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You have lots of questions that are all caused by a bad, non-normalized data model. Don't use JSON, use many tables with foreign key relationships like Codd wants it to be.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I updated my post. Column type is jsonb. I can't change this.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output - for **multiple** rows from that table, not just a single JSON value. But I agree with Laurenz: all your problems stem mainly from the fact that you are misusing JSON for something it was never intended for. Some of your problems would also be easier to solve if you upgraded to Postgres 12. Relying on full text search to filter JSON data also seems a wrong approach

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was updated my post

Answer (score 1):

This could be done like this:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_set(data, '{availability}', 
                        (select jsonb_agg(item order by (item ->> 'price')::numeric)
                         from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'availability') as x(item))
                 ) as data
from product
where ...
```